# I have to create a seperate folder for separate user using php

Tags: php

I am using php for first time, i have task to create a seperate directory for seperate users using php.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
 <?php
mkdir("/".$username."/", 0700);
$target_path = "/".$username."/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "<h1>The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded</h1>";
    echo "<h1><a href='claim_try.php'>Back to claim page.</a></h1>";
} else{
    echo "<h1>There was an error uploading the file, please try again!</h1>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you even try to google something like 'php create dir'

Comment: S but the codes didnt work

Comment: Share your code, add it to your post

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: try this ,$usersname_temp ="/".$username."/"; mkdir($usersname_temp, 0777); in the place of mkdir("/".$username."/", 0700);

Comment: it is showing error

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: as in the program. there was an error uploading the file

Comment: Did your teacher tell you "Achieve this task by asking people over stackoverflow to do it"?

Comment: s he especially  mentioned your name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and i am able to create separate directory for specific user.I created the directories based on time and storing the files inside them

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (!file_exists($usersname)) {
   // Makes directory if not exist
    //mkdir('directory_Name', 0777, true);
    mkdir($usersname,0777, true);
}
```

Read this,  **[mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)**

Comment: i need to create a folder with the username

Comment: @Mahesh Kumar :  replace your 'username' in place of 'directory_Name'

Comment: How to create dynamically when user uploads any file

Comment: thanks but the problem is whenever any user uploads any file from form, dynamically the folder should be created and the uploaded file should be stored in it.

Comment: @Mahesh Kumar :  pass $usersname if directory is not exist then it will  Makes directory and move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"data/".$usersname); pass path in  move_uploaded_file or whatever you use.

Comment: i have tested your edited code but it is not showing any error and the directory is also not created

Comment: do you check on same location where the php file is exist(mkdir code)?